# OIDC results in crash Azure Kubernetes

Tags: weaviate

Cannot for the life of me get Weaviate to launch with OIDC authentication - I have tried every combination under the sun and the pod falls into a CrashLoopBackOff.

I can successfully deploy with the defaults (anon access = true and no admin list); but as soon as OIDC is added, no luck.

Is there something wrong with my config? I add the config as per the documentation to the values.yaml before continuing on with the instructions.

I should note, not at all familiar with Kubernetes and using this as a learning experience.

Thanks so much for any help

YAML (from azure portal):

```
data:
  conf.yaml: |-
    ---
    authentication:
      anonymous_access:
        enabled: false
      oidc:
        client_id: client-id
        enabled: true
        issuer: https://issuerURL/authorize/
        skip_client_id_check: false
        username_claim: email
    authorization:
      admin_list:
        enabled: true
        users:
        - user@user.com

    query_defaults:
      limit: 100
    debug: false
```

Answer (score 0):

For the issuer URL with Azure you will want it to be of the format `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/v2.0`. You can find this via Azure > App Registrations > Endpoints > OpenID Metadata document (without the `.well-known/openid-configuration` suffix.

As of Weaviate version 1.15.3, the Weaviate console and python client do not work with Azure but there is an issue to [fix](https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/2224) this planned for 1.16.